# How do you give a thumbnail to other websites?

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

When a user posts a link from a website on Reddit or Facebook or similar, they normally have an image associated with it.

Is there anyway of dictating what that image is in the header of the html file? I imagine that there must be a meta tag, similar to description and author, that allows this to be dictated?

I have searched Stack overflow for similar questions and the internet in general but couldn't find anything, which makes me wonder if my question is phrased wrongly.

Comment: You may be referring to the og:image meta property. just google search that and see if it fits your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to display a certain image when posting a link to your website, try something like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url to specific image you want" />
<meta property="og:title" content="name of page" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description of content" />
```

Also, you can troubleshoot things like these on this Facebook debugging website:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Hope this helps, Good Luck.